Etymology of English hapax legomenon (word that appears only once) "flother"
I was recently perusing the Wikipedia page for "Hapax legomenon", a term that refers to words that appear only once in a given corpus/context (rather than nonce words, which are words like "Jabberwock" invented for a single purpose and otherwise not a word). I happened to come across the lovely "flother", apparently an English hapax legomenon meaning "snowflake". The word was stated to have appeared only once in English (in a 1275 Middle English manuscript called The XI Pains of Hell)^1. I have, however, noticed a few various spellings: Wikipedia spells it "flother", Wiktionary spells it "floþre", and a version of the text of the manuscript I was able to find from the Middle English Texts Series spells it "flothre". Notwithstanding these spelling variations (which, as I understand it, are not particularly important owing to the lack of spelling standardization in that era), I have one main question:

Is it possible to discern any etymology of the term "flother", whether from Old English, Norman, or otherwise?

And two secondary questions:

How might "flother" have been pronounced in 1275, and how might it have evolved up to the modern era had it survived? (Not knowing the IPA or the details of the Great Vowel Shift, I'd notate the way I read it as "fl-UH-thr" rhyming with "mother".)

I would be very thankful for answers to any of these questions, or even somewhere to look for answers. Thanks!
^1: Upon checking the talk page, apparently the word also appears in a book from 1962 in reference to its being given as a part of some specification for "painted wainscot" from 1597-8. And searching further, it appears that it may also appear more times in some sort of glossary. I leave the question of whether this word should continue to appear as a hapax legomenon on the Wikipedia page to others.

According to the Middle English Dictionary at the University of Michigan there are three attestations, all from the 14th c. So it's not a hapax legomenon, but close.

Thank you. I bring that up in a footnote at the end of my question.

The letter in the Wiktionary version is thorn, an obsolete letter representing the 'th' sound, so not really a spelling variant.

Mo saulen tholieth ther sucche wowe / Thane be flothre in the snowe. More souls suffer there [in Hell] such torment / than (there) be flakes in the snow".

I'd guess that if it was sufficiently old, it was originally pronounced with a long /o:/ like OE brōþor (brother) and mōdor (mother). Though quite when the change in pronunciation occurred is unclear, and it wouldn't have happened all at once.

@KateBunting I assumed it counted because even if it was the same letter it was different in a strictly orthographic sense. I accept your note, however, of course.

@StuartF So it might have been something like “fl-OH-thr” or “FLOW-thr” rhyming with “loather”?

The obsolete rare word flother meaning 'a flake (of snow)' likely shares the same etymon with the current word flake, which could be the Old English flæðra 'plural flakes of snow'. OED says "of unknown origin" for flother but compares it to the OE word flæðra cited by Junius.
OED says "of unknown origin" for flake also but provides more details in its etymology. I'm citing the relevant part below which mentions other possible cognates up to pre-Germanic:

Sense 1 has not been found earlier than Chaucer, though Junius cites an Old English ‘flacea ⁊ flæðra, flaws or flakes of snow’; it appears to be cognate with Old Norse flóke flock of wool, lock of hair, and perhaps with Old High German floccho of same meaning (if this be genuinely a Germanic word, representing a pre-Germanic *pləgnén-, and not an adoption of Latin floccus); the Old English flacor, fluttering, has also been compared.
Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “flake (n.2), Etymology,” December 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7860819733.

Flother is probably pronounced as /ˈflɔθər/ 'FLAW-thuhr' or /ˈflɑθər/ 'FLAH-thuhr' in U.S. English (based on the word frother). It could be /ˈfləðər/ 'FLAH-dhuhr' also based on the word smother. I'm uncertain about the historical pronunciations.
